# finding the size of an string array that saves integers C

Tags: c

I am currently working on a project where I am manipulating command line data, but I can't seem to get it work if I initialize the size of the array before.

```
char* len2[50]; // will store "1","2","3" from command line args

int size_arr = sizeof(len2) / sizeof(len2[0]);
printf("%d", size_arr);
```

this will input 50 when I am looking for it to input 3. How would I be able to find the size?

Comment: Where are you getting 3 from?

Comment: Do you mean something like `char len2[3][50];` ?

Comment: Please use the word "input" for the things the user is typing. The other things should use different words (such as calculate, output, print etc..)

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to find is the number of items. Since there are 3 numbers I'll be getting from the command line, I want to be able to manipulate the array using 3 for a for or while loop for example

Comment: `char *len2[3]` can be assigned with `len2[0] = argv[1];` etc.

Comment: The number of command line parameters is given by `argc`.

Comment: Wondering what you *actually* want to do. Might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: sizeof is a compile-time operation.  result will always be 50 in this case

Comment: *'will store "1","2","3" from command line args'* – why would you want a duplicate array at all? You have that already with `argv` (second argument to main function), which you even can legally modify, if you feel need to, both the pointer array of `argv` as well as the individual arguments (`argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, ...) – as long as you do **not** write beyond the respective original array lengths (i.e. the location of the original null-terminator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int size_arr = sizeof(len2) / sizeof(len2[0]);
```

`sizeof(len2)` asks for the total allocated size of `len2` in bytes. This only works because C knows how many you allocated at compile time and turns it into a constant. It doesn't tell you which ones you've filled in. C does not keep track of that; you have to.

Because `len2` is an array of pointers, you can mark the end with a null pointer. The term for this is a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). First, be sure to initialize the array to null.

```
// This will initialize the entire array to NULL
char* len2[50] = {NULL};
```

Now you can find how many elements are in the array by looking for the first null, or by hitting the allocated size.

```
size_t len2_size = sizeof(len2) / sizeof(len2[0]);

int size = 0;
for( ; len2[size] != NULL && size < len2_size; size++ );

printf("size: %d\n", size);
```

This is, incidentally, basically how C strings work. The end of the string is marked with a 0.

Alternatively, you can store the allocated size and number of elements in a struct and keep track, but that's another question.

Finally, if you're just reading command line arguments, use `argc` and `argv`. `argc` is the size of `argv`. `argv[0]` is the name of the program, and the rest are the command line arguments.

```
int main( const int argc, const char **argv) {
    printf("%d arguments in argv\n", argc-1);
}
```

And `argv` is also terminated with a NULL pointer so it's easy to iterate through.

```
// Because argv[0] is the name of the program,
// start at 1 and read until you hit a null pointer.
for( int i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++ ) {
  printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just that I'd make `size` a `size_t` as well – avoiding signed/unsigned integer comparison... *'how C strings work'* – and actually `argv` as well (`argc` <-> null-termination being redundant...). `main` signature is none of those provided by the standard, arguments should be non-const to match.

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble explaining it but you understood what I was trying to ask. I am going to be using an ending pointer in order to indicate when the loop should stop.

Comment: @AnaPacheco Sentinel value is *one* way you can do, and a totally valid one. Storing the number of items in a separate variable is another one (with the advantage that you can easier iterate backwards and the disadvantage of having to pass around both variables together). Sentinels *can* have the disadvantage of consuming a value that *might* be part of the valid range, mainly if integrals are involved, not an issue with pointers, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua Unsigned integers add a complication, I tend to avoid them when answering for new programmers. Thank you for the note about `argv` being null terminated. I am curious if there's any compiler that will warn on the use of `const` in main.

Comment: @Schwern That sounds to me a bit like 'use a hammer to drive a screw into the wall because a screw driver is too complicated to use'... Signed and unsigned are both valid tools and one should learn to use both appropriately. Unsigned, if applied at the right place (like indexing a data structure) can even remove complication as you don't need to check the lower bound, which is 0 anyway ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua The OP is struggling with the very basics.

Comment: @Schwern ... and thus will wonder about the compiler warning about signed/unsigned comparison ;) Well, not sure, would it even be better letting him/her learn swimming by jumping into cold water?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> I guess what I'm trying to find is the number of items. Since there are 3 numbers I'll be getting from the command line, I want to be able to manipulate the array using 3 for a for or while loop for example.

According to the standard you have two versions of `main` function available (while the implementation defining further ones is legal):

```
int main();
int main(int, char**);
```

The second form gets the command line parameters passed to directly while the first form can be used if command line parameters are irrelevant.

Typically (but not necessarily) these two arguments get named `argc` and `argv` with `argc` containing the total number of command line arguments and `argv` a null-terminated array to the actual arguments. First one of is always the name that has been used to call the programme (which can differ in some cases from the actual executable name, e.g. if symbolic links are involved) which you might want to skip.

So a programme simply iterating over all arguments and printing them back to console might look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(++argv; *argv; ++argv)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *argv);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with first `++argv` skipping the programme name, `*argv` profiting from and testing for the null-terminator of the array and second `++argv` being the normal loop post operation.

If you want to see the programme name as well you might just skip very first pointer increment:

```
for(;*argv;++argv)
```

Alternative variants might use an integer to count up to `argc` – just a matter of personal taste...